# Discretizing spatial derivatives of second order PDE.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, wave-equation, fluid-dynamics

I am working on a MATLAB assingment, where I try to work out water waves. The height of the waves is given by $u$. Now $x \in [-L,L]$, which to me is the position of the wave. The PDE is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}} +3u^{2} \right).
\end{equation}

The first thing I need to do is to discretize the spatial derivatives using centered differences. Now I really have no clue what they mean by this. I looked online, but no luck there either.
As far as my English goes, I expect that we 'cut up' the time, thereby making time discreet, and than see how the function reacts to this. I guess I am trying to find the $u$ given an initial value for each position $x$ at each discrete time point $t_{n}$.

Does this make sense at all?

Comment: You need to look up finite difference methods before you try something like this, you're trying to run before you can walk. Start by looking at finite difference methods for ODE's, once you are comfortable look at PDE's, then you can do this problem.

Comment: @David; thanks, I will do this and if able answer the question myself.